# Are the jQuery method .animate and .delay not allowed in Google Apps Scripts?

Tags: google-apps-script

When using jQuery within the HtmlService in a Google Apps Script, are the **.animate** and **.delay** methods not supported? I can get .show() and .hide() to work, but I can't get any animations to work.

For example, in a sidebar, I would like to temporarily display a notice using:

```
$('#notice').show().delay(5000).hide();
```

The delay appears to be ignored. I've tested the following, and it works fine, so it seems that the .delay method is the only thing not working in this case. I've also tried using .animate, but it does not seem to work, either.

```
$('#notice').show();
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The jQuery method `.delay()` won't work in-between `.show()` and `.hide()` as it can only be used in conjunction with animations. You will need to use

```
setTimout(function(){
   $('#notice').hide();
}, 5000);
```

Comment: This is noted on the .delay() page in the jQuery UI docs: http://api.jquery.com/delay/

Answer (score 0):

Those are not supported. Its documented in the limitations section of htmlService.